# Remote access to Microsoft SQL Server 2012 with JDBC: alternative to username/password authentication?

Tags: sql-server, jsp, authentication, web-applications, jdbc

I want to access a remote Microsoft SQL Server 2012 database from a Java web application (JSP and surrounding classes) using Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0. I was told the username/password for the database, but would prefer not storing the verbatim password as part of the web application's configuration.

Does Microsoft SQL Server 2012 support another authentication method where I could pass e.g. some kind of service token instead from a remote (not necessarily Windows-based) host, and more generally, what are best practices for storing and configuring database access configuration parameters in such a scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a Windows box in an Active Directory (AD) environment, you can use integrated security. This will connect to SQL Server using the AD security credentials of the current process (Windows account).

Specify `integratedSecurity=true` instead of user name and password in the connection string. See [Building the Connection URL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx) for more information.

SQL Server also supports Kerberos authentication using the Microsoft JDBC driver for Linux as specified with the [`authorizationScheme` connection string](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122(v=sql.110).aspx) keyword.

Comment: +1 If the web app is running on Tomcat on Windows box A as user A1 and the database is on Microsoft SQL Server 2012 on Windows box B and is owned by user B1, how would I configure AD such that B allows JDBC access from A1 with integrated security? For my case, A = B may be realistic, but A1 = B1 FWIK is not.

Comment: The database owner shouldn't matter for routine application access.  Grant user A1 account access to SQL Server with `CREATE LOGIN [<your-domain-name>\A1] FROM WINDOWS;`.  Then grant access to the database with `CREATE USER [<your-domain-name>\A1];`, and grant permissions to the database objects directly accessed with GRANT...ON <object-name> TO [<your-domain-name>\A1]`.